# When exactly did TeX.SE graduate?

Tags: discussion, area51, graduating-sites

[TeX.SE is listed on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends). However, the right-hand column only references that "this site launched ... 8 years ago."

[image]

It

- was [proposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUu4o.png) on June 2, 2010;
- had a [commitment start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jCG.png) on June 22, 2010;
- went into [private beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAz3u.png) on July 26, 2010; and finally
- went into [public beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66rLj.png) on August 2, 2010

before launching. When was the actual launch day/graduation?

It's not possible to establish this date purely based on questions on the site, since questions asked during the establishment phase on Area 51 - private and public beta - eventually end up on the site and therefore precede the launch date. As an example, the first question on TeX.SE (by reference in the URL as `/questions/1`) - [Automatically define macros in LyX documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1/5764) - is dated July 27, 2010.

Related: [Tooltip showing date/time of site launch](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20646/90733)